# Solve this ODE system

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have this ODE system:$$x'(t) = ax(t)+ by(t)$$ $$y'(t)= cx(t) + dy(t)$$ $$x(0)= 2, y(0)= 1$$ how do I get the coefficients $a,b,c,d$? I know how to solve ODE with two variables, but now sure how to solve the system...

Comment: which are the coefficients you are talking about? Please, be more precise and add your efforts if any.

Comment: @the_candyman a, b, c, d will be the coefficients.

Comment: @the_candyman honestly i don't know how to solve this because the derivatives are taken w.r.t t  and $x'(t)$ depends on y(t) but y(t) is also depends on x(t)....

Comment: wait, generally $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ are given... changing these values end up with very different solution of your system of ODE. You need to find $x(t)$ and $y(t)$, not the coefficients!

Comment: @the_candyman I thought it would be the same thing, in order to find the x(t) y(t), you will need to find a, b, c, d anyways.. Given the initial values x(0) y(0), would you be able to find abcd though?

Answer (score 3):

I will show you why what you are asking is wrong giving you some examples.

**Example 1**
$$\begin{cases}
x'(t) = 2x(t) + 0y(t)\\
y'(t) = 0x(t) - 3y(t)
\end{cases}$$
In this case, you have $a = 2$, $b=c= 0$ and $d = -3$. The general solution of this is the following:
$$\begin{cases}
x(t) = Ae^{2t}\\
y(t) = Be^{-3t}
\end{cases}$$
Imposing initial conditions ($x(0) = 2$, $y(0) =1$), then:
$$\begin{cases}
x(0) = A = 2\\
y(0) = B = 1
\end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{cases}
x(t) = 2e^{2t}\\
y(t) = e^{-3t}
\end{cases}.$$

**Example 2**
$$\begin{cases}
x'(t) = 2x(t) + y(t)\\
y'(t) = 0x(t) - 3y(t)
\end{cases}$$
In this case, you have $a = 2$, $b=1$, $c= 0$ and $d = -3$. The general solution of this is the following:
$$\begin{cases}
x(t) = Ae^{2t} + Be^{-3t}\\
y(t) = Ce^{-3t}
\end{cases}$$
Imposing initial conditions ($x(0) = 2$, $y(0) =1$), then:
$$\begin{cases}
x(0) = A+ B= 2 \Rightarrow B = 2-A\\
y(0) = C = 1
\end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{cases}
x(t) = Ae^{2t} + (2-A)e^{-3t}\\
y(t) = e^{-3t}
\end{cases}.$$

In order to find $A$, substitute this in the first differential equation:
$$x'(t) = 2x(t)+y(t) \Rightarrow
2Ae^{2t}-3(2-A)e^{-3t} = 2(Ae^{2t} + (2-A)e^{-3t}) + e^{-3t} \Rightarrow \\
(-3(2-A)-2(2-A)-1)e^{-3t} = 0 \Rightarrow (5A-11)e^{-3t} = 0
$$
This must be $0$ for all $t$, and hence $5A-11=0 \Rightarrow A =\frac{11}{5}$, yielding to:

$$x(t) = \frac{11}{5}e^{2t} - \frac{1}{5} e^{-3t}$$

**Example 3**
$$\begin{cases}
x'(t) = 0x(t) + y(t)\\
y'(t) = -x(t) + 0y(t)
\end{cases}$$
In this case, you have $a = 0$, $b=1$, $c= -1$ and $d = 0$. The general solution of this is the following:
$$\begin{cases}
x(t) = A\sin(t) + B\cos(t)\\
y(t) = C\sin(t) + D\cos(t)
\end{cases}$$
Imposing initial conditions ($x(0) = 2$, $y(0) =1$), then:
$$\begin{cases}
x(0) = B= 2 \\
y(0) = D = 1
\end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{cases}
x(t) = A\sin(t) + 2\cos(t)\\
y(t) = C\sin(t) + \cos(t)
\end{cases}.$$

Performing similar calculation as in example 2, you can determine $A$ and $C$ and at the end you get:
$$
\begin{cases}
x(t) = \sin(t) + 2\cos(t)\\
y(t) = -2\sin(t) + \cos(t)
\end{cases}.$$

**Concluding**
Changing $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ will **dramatically** changes the solution of the set of ODEs. You don't have to find $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$, but you have to find $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ that satisfies the set of ODEs. For these reasons, you need to **know** $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$.

I skipped a bunch of calculations here. In order to solve the problem, you need to know some facts about matrices, eigenvalues, eigenvectors and function basis of linear/constant coefficient differential equations.

You can refer to [this](http://www.math.psu.edu/tseng/class/Math251/Notes-LinearSystems.pdf) for example, or just google around. Hope this can help.

On the other hand, if both $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are given, then one can try to find out $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ (inverse problem). But it does not seem to be the case...

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful !!